# Search performance, Active Record, Postgres and Trigram indexes, how to split a query to force postgres to use indexes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a table with parts. These parts have a field where all the relevant info is grouped.
I have to perform a search on this field for every word in a search input, using ILIKE with wildcards in both sides. The table has 1.2M rows at the moment.

I have been reading about the best way to index the field to search, and finally decided to go with GIN trigram indexes. The problem is that the query takes too much time when one of the words is shorter than 3 characters, making the search going from blazingly fast to take way longer than 10 secs in many cases.

> Examples and measures.

- This query makes use of the trigram index and gets done quickly.

`SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" WHERE (parts.eureka ILIKE '%rodamiento%') AND (parts.eureka ILIKE '%skf%') AND (parts.eureka ILIKE '%asf%')`

The analyze output is as follows:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on parts  (cost=716.03..741.93 rows=13 width=195) (actual time=21.194..21.346 rows=29 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: ((eureka ~~* '%rodamiento%'::text) AND (eureka ~~* '%fag%'::text) AND (eureka ~~* '%asf%'::text))
  Heap Blocks: exact=17
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on parts_eureka_idx  (cost=0.00..716.03 rows=13 width=0) (actual time=21.164..21.164 rows=29 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((eureka ~~* '%rodamiento%'::text) AND (eureka ~~* '%fag%'::text) AND (eureka ~~* '%asf%'::text))
Planning Time: 0.614 ms
Execution Time: 21.467 ms
```

- Now on the other hand, this other query uses seq. scan, and it takes way longer. Notice that the only change is `%as%` instead of `%asf%`

`SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" WHERE (parts.eureka ILIKE '%rodamiento%') AND (parts.eureka ILIKE '%skf%') AND (parts.eureka ILIKE '%as%')`

```
Gather  (cost=1000.00..85599.12 rows=87 width=195) (actual time=0.337..3988.485 rows=6548 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 1
  Workers Launched: 1
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on parts  (cost=0.00..84590.42 rows=51 width=195) (actual time=0.116..3940.638 rows=3274 loops=2)
        Filter: ((eureka ~~* '%rodamiento%'::text) AND (eureka ~~* '%fag%'::text) AND (eureka ~~* '%as%'::text))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 637016
Planning Time: 1.003 ms
Execution Time: 3989.197 ms
```

The code for the search is as follows:

`Part.rb`

```
class Part < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_copy_target
  scope :tipo, ->(tipo) { where tipo: tipo }

  def self.search(params)
    recordset = Part.all
    recordset = recordset.tipo(params[:tipo]) if params[:tipo].present?
    recordset = search_keywords(params[:search], recordset)
    recordset.order(:price_amount1)
  end

  private

  def self.search_keywords(query, recordset)
    keywords = query.to_s.unicode_normalize(:nfc).gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/, " ").strip.split
    if query
      keywords.each do |keyword|
        recordset = recordset.where("parts.eureka ILIKE :q", q: "%#{keyword}%")
      end
      recordset
    end
  end
end
```

I was thinking about splitting the query like this:

1. One query to search the words with length >= 3 to leverage the trigram indexes.
2. Over the returned recordset, make another query for the rest of words. I assume that making a seq scan over a reduced recordset will take shorter than the seq scan shown in the previous analyze output.

Is this a good idea? How can I tell active record to act like that? Any other sugestions to improve this?

Comment: If your ultimate goal is to improve query and making search operation fast I suggest to use Ransack (https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a proposal to fix this problem](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAOBaU_YGP5-BEt5Cc0=zMve92vocPzD+XiZgiZs1kjY0cj=XBg@mail.gmail.com), but it has not yet been reviewed and committed.  So I don't know if it will make it into version 13 or not.

You can combine your two steps into one, by forcing postgresql not to think it can use the index for the short query strings:

```
select * from foo where (x ilike '%long%) and (x||'' ilike '%sh%')
```

The secret is `||''`, which inhibits the index usage on that clause without changing the results.

Now how to reverse engineer this into ruby is not a task for me, but based on the snippet you posted it doesn't seem like it should be hard.

Comment: Thank you, I will research how to translate this into ruby as you say and I will let you know.

Comment: It works, the same query goes from 3000 ms to 20ms. Thank you!